# Assigning a string in cookie variable not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, httpcookie

I am trying to save a string inside cookie variable . but after debug i saw it took only half of it.

```
string cs="metadata=res://*/Models.ADModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ADModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ADModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=192.168.10.104;initial catalog=AlarmDirectorDTU;persist security info=True;user id=aduserly;password=PasswordLY;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'"
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ConnectionString", cs));
```

During debugging i saw

```
Request.Cookies["ConnectionString"].Value
```

Value of this cookie is-

```
"metadata=res://*/Models.ADModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ADModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ADModel.msl"
```

please suggest me how to save this complete string in this cookie variable,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.Net you can use System.Web.HttpUtility to safely encode the cookie value before writing to the cookie and convert it back to its original form on reading it out.

```
// Encode
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cookieData);

// Decode
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedCookieData);
```

This will stop semicolon, ampersands and equals signs splitting a value into a bunch of name/value pairs as it is written to a cookie.

Your code will become :

```
string cs="metadata=res://*/Models.ADModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ADModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ADModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=192.168.10.104;initial catalog=AlarmDirectorDTU;persist security info=True;user id=aduserly;password=PasswordLY;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'";

var encodedData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cs);

Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ConnectionString", encodedData));
var cookieData = Request.Cookies["ConnectionString"].Value; 

var decodedData = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(cookieData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are handled by the browser by delimiting with a semicolon. You can safely encode the cookie by using `System.Web.HttpUtility`.

```
//encode
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cs);
```

Comment: i m passing this variable to my edmx container which not accepting this encoded string